# A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found - XCode

Tags: xcode, tvos, apple-tv, kodi

I am trying to deploy Kodi on my Apple TV 4th Gen. Actually I already did this procedure in 2 different Apple TV 4th Gen before and it worked.

I am following this tutorial (as I followed before):

http://www.redmondpie.com/how-to-sideload-install-kodi-on-apple-tv-4/

But when I get to the Step 4 when I need to `Fix Issue` I get an error "A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found". My account is already a Developer Account (Free account). I already tried to create a new account as well but did not work.

Answer (score 1):

when you press fix issue, you select a profile like com.example.kodi.
here is the mistake that you made, you need to select the profile you signed in your name in the iOS app signer then you resign it.

Comment: but I need to "Fix Issues" before going thought the iOS app signer. Sorry I did not understand, could you explain in another way?